# Rocket name request: rocket company launching a rocket with a "punny" name

Tags: rockets, identify-this-object

I'm trying to recall the name of a rocket. I read / watched about it this year, or late last year; unfortunately I cannot find it in my history.

The name of this rocket, created by a company whose name I also do not remember, (or some part of the rocket - perhaps even the name of the launches) was "punny" - amusing in some way.

This was one of this company’s first launches, they’re still a small company and I think they’re based in the US, although possibly Australia. The rocket was small; I don’t know if it’s orbital class, but I don’t think it’s been to or it yet.

I'm thinking the name might be something like "alpha test" or "experimental rocket" or "rocket" or "this might crash" - something just a bit silly.

Unfortunately, I cannot think of any more details.

Comment: @uhoh no, it’s certainly more obscure [than the BFR]. Likely the US. It’s one of the company’s first rockets, so I imagine small. I don’t think it’s been to orbit. Edited to clarify

Comment: Looks great, thanks! It's not the name of the upcoming Rocket Labs launch of their Electron rocket, which is being referred to as "[It's business time](https://techcrunch.com/2018/06/26/watch-rocket-labs-first-commercial-launch-its-business-time/) *and will be launching from New Zealand*, is it? Or their previous launch, which they called "[Still Testing](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/news/updates/rocket-lab-delays-still-testing-launch-attempt/)"? or before that; "[It's a Test](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/news/updates/rocket-lab-successfully-makes-it-to-space-2/)"?

Comment: @uhoh yes! “It’s a test”. I can’t believe I didn’t look into that further! This topic came up due to my discussion with a friend about their upcoming launch. Please, post an answer!

Comment: @uhoh I’ll post in the morning if you’ve not, it’s getting late  (well, early) here; but it was you that found the answer! I would like to see more punny names if they exist, so I’ll certainly hold-off on accepting any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the Electron rocket (so named because, unlike any other orbital rocket I know of, it uses electrical pumps to feed its engines), which is built and operated by Rocket Lab, and launches from New Zealand (though it's a US company). Their first two launches were "It's a Test" (aborted in flight) and "Still Testing" (reached orbit and deployed payload successfully). Their third flight is named "It's Business Time"

Comment: They are still continuing the Punny Names, aside from a few serious ones for the old-school establishments, and even those seem to be chilling out recently. See : https://www.rocketlabusa.com/missions/completed-missions/